# Starting webcam using pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am pretty new at python and pygame. I was trying to open the webcam using pygame. I have the following code.

```
    import pygame, sys
    import pygame.camera as camera
    from pygame.locals import *

    pygame.init()
    camera.init()

    screen=pygame.display,set_mode((640,480))

    cam=pygame.camera.Camera("/dev/video0",(640,480))
    cam.start()

    while 1:
        image=cam.get_image()
        screen.blit(image,(0,0))
        pygame.display.update()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==pygame.Quit:
                sys.exit()
```

There's an error which says:

```
    File "F:\camera", line 6, in <module>

    camera.init()

    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pygame\camera.py", line 42, in init

    import _camera

    ImportError: No module named _camera
```

I have searched around the web but they all use this. Any help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using Windows.

[From the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/camera.html):

> Pygame currently supports only Linux and v4l2 cameras.

So you're not going to be able to do that.